# zookeeper unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I am getting quite a few major issues in Cloudera Hadoop 2.0 cluster that coincides with the following errors on zookeeper that happens many times a day.

I am unable to find the root cause of this.

Any help is appreciated.

`2016-04-11 14:48:30,872 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:48:49,584 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:49:07,239 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:49:25,291 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:49:42,779 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:50:00,613 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:50:17,976 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:50:35,957 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
2016-04-11 14:50:54,676 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler: Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open`

Comment: Check this i hope it may fix your issue...https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/zookeeper-error-Unexpected-exception-causing-shutdown-while-sock/td-p/30914

Comment: Thank you, Krishna, I am going to try it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out was 2 layer issue:

The above error was happening while leader election was going on for too long.

The cause of the leader election taking too long was corrupt data on one of the 3 zookeeper servers.

Once data files from /var/lib/zookeeper were blown away and zookeeper restarted, leader election succeeded and that in turned stopped the problem above.